# Some of my apps disappeared after wiping cache and dalvic cache. Why?

Tags: applications, cyanogenmod, cache

I am running Cyanogenmod 12.1 snapshot ROM on my Moto G 2nd gen. Today I Installed Xposed framework and Wiped dalvic and cache. After reboot I noticed that some of my apps have disappeared. Only grayed out icons can be seen. What should I do now?

Answer (score -1):

As for as i know, when a rom boots up for a first time dalvik goes each and every apks and extract the dex (Android programs are compiled into .dex (Dalvik Executable) files) and put in the cache.So next time when you use your mobile it start faster and improved the performance, so when you wiped dalvik cache, it only clear cache memory. it will not delete application data.

i cannot say exactly one solution for your problem without getting more information, try to reinstall apk, maybe it will solve your problem because data is not deleted.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did not try to reinstall but was waiting... It took about half an hour and suddenly my apps appeared. Rebooted again and it did not happen again. Now phone runs normally.

Comment: then good luck,